# Vaadin demos with different effects

Tags: vaadin

i am new to Vaadin -- trying out some of the demos-- such as [this](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-splitpanel.html).

However, i'm seeing the following to the very same code when i run it in my workspace:

[image]

My code is the same as the example on this page-- i only called a different `Tree` constructor for simplicity. The splitters and `Panel` I'm using are all from `com.vaadin.ui.*`:

```
private Component panels() {
    // Have a panel to put stuff in
    Panel panel = new Panel("Split Panels Inside This Panel");

    // Have a horizontal split panel as its content
    HorizontalSplitPanel hsplit = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
    panel.setContent(hsplit);

    // Put a component in the left panel
    Tree tree = new Tree("Menu");
    hsplit.setFirstComponent(tree);

    // Put a vertical split panel in the right panel
    VerticalSplitPanel vsplit = new VerticalSplitPanel();
    hsplit.setSecondComponent(vsplit);

    // Put other components in the right panel
    vsplit.addComponent(new Label("Here's the upper panel"));
    vsplit.addComponent(new Label("Here's the lower panel"));
    return panel;
}
```

Then, i'm simply calling this method from `init()` of my UI connector:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

    setContent(panels());

}
```

This happened to just about every splitter, layout, panel demos i've been on.

What am i missing?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define that your panel's height is 100%.

You can do it for example by saying

```
panel.setHeight("100%");
```

Comment: Docs: [click me](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-settings.html#layout.settings.size)

Comment: the demos & docs don't seem to be updated with the latest Vaadin version(?) i installed the latest. is there more up-to-date documentation?

Comment: @user6401178 something specific you found to be outdated?